# Setting log levels with Ruby Logger

Tags: ruby, performance, logging, scripting

I'm using a Ruby gem that utilizes the [`Logger`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) class.

Is there a way to set log levels globally like in [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) with an `.xml` or `.properties` file?

I don't want the output to be written at all. My concern is that printing all those logging statements drains performance.

P. S.: It's just a simple script, I'm not using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I really doubt that logging is slowing down your program that much, although it is still good practice to turn down your log level in production code. The bigger problem becomes storage space.

Comment: Try setting the level of the logger object.

Comment: What gem are you using? The solution depends on how the logger is implemented and whether it is exposed to you.

Comment: @mikeryz I'm using [rubydns](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubydns). [This](https://github.com/ioquatix/rubydns/blob/master/lib/rubydns/server.rb) is the source code of the class where logging occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the gem you're using is kind enough to expose the logger as a attr_accessor, you can simply do this:

```
some_server = Server.new
some_server.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
```

Obviously feel free to chose the log level that is appropriate for your environment and application (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also the initializer for that class is dead simple, so if you have a lot of these servers, you could monkey-patch it to set the log level as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not creating the server myself. I'm using [this](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rubydns/#Usage) entry point. Can I still set the log level then?
As you may have already noticed, I ain't a Ruby expert.

Comment: Check out this example - it looks like you can access @logger within the block: https://github.com/ioquatix/rubydns/blob/e4bc9f11da58944c73c7418ec1cb56ebbe06091b/test/examples/wikipedia-dns.rb